# Is there any way to find the nodes in the each subtree of each node having distance equal to height of the subtree?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, arrays, java

We are given a tree of N nodes from 1 to N where node 1 is the root of the tree.
For each node i from 1 to N, you have to find the numbers of nodes which are in the subtree of i and are at distance equal to height of subtree of i.

Distance between a & b = total number of edges in path from a to b,height of subtree = maximum distance of the root of the subtree to any node in the subtree.

I have tried to create an algorithm using dfs using adjancey list of arraylist in java but got nowhere.

example input and output:
input:

```
first line:
4--> no of nodes---
next each line represents connection of nodes
(1 2),
(2 3),
(2 4)
```

output:

```
-->space separated output for each node as a root.
2 2 1 1
```

Comment: You say you "have tried to create an algorithm". What were your ideas thus far? Where did you get stuck? Could you expound a little more on how you used DFS?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can notice that the nodes you are looking for are necessarly leaves of the tree (or sub-tree). What you are looking for, in each sub-tree, are the leaves that are at the largest distance from the root.

Let's call:

- $L_k$, the list of the furthest leaves in the sub-tree rooting at node $k$ (the answer to your problem).
- $h_k$, the distance from node $k$ to the furthest leaves of the sub-tree rooting at node $k$ (what you call height).

For all leaves, you have:

- $h_k$ = 0
- $L_k$ = [k]

For all other node, you have:

- $h_k$ = $max_i (f_i) + 1$ for each $i$ child of $k$
- $L_k$ = $sum_i (L_i)$  for each $i$ child of $k$ if $h_k$ == $h_i$+1

NB: by $sum$, I mean the concatenation of all the lists verificating the condition.

Globally, you can do a DFS, and once you explored all the subsequent paths from a node $k$, you are able to compute $h_k$ and $L_k$.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in DFS Mechanism, here the code is

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
  
public class codeNew  
{ 
    static Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int n = inn.nextInt(); 
    
    static int count1[] = new int[n+1]; 
    static ArrayList<Integer> adj[] = new ArrayList[n+1]; 

    static void numberOfNodes(int s, int e) 
    { 
        if(s != 1  && adj[s].size() == 1) {
            count1[s] = 1; 
        }else
        {
            count1[s] = 0; 
        }
        
        for(Integer u: adj[s]) 
        { 

            if(u == e) 
                continue; 

            numberOfNodes(u ,s); 
            count1[s] += count1[u]; 
        } 
    } 
      
    // function to add edges in graph 
    static void addEdge(int a, int b) 
    { 
        adj[a].add(b); 
        adj[b].add(a); 
    } 
      
    // function to print result 
    static void printNumberOfNodes() 
    { 
        for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
             System.out.print(count1[i]); 
             if(i != n)
             {
                System.out.print(" ");
             }
        }
           
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) 
            adj[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            int x = inn.nextInt();
            int y = inn.nextInt();
            addEdge(x,y); 
        }
        numberOfNodes(1, 0); 
        printNumberOfNodes(); 
              
    } 
  
}
```

Input is

```
4
1 2
2 3
2 4
```

Output is
`2 2 1 1`

Comment: We're not a coding site, and we're not looking for answers that consist solely of code.  Instead, we'd like to see concise pseudocode, explanations, ideas, and/or proofs of correctness.

Comment: @D.W. ok got it, Sorry!